# JAXB marshalling @XmlElementRef name property not coming as Name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-annotations

I am not getting name as tag name for @XmlElementRef.

Element declaration in parent elemnet:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Agents",  type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfGeneralAgent> agents;
```

Declaration of class ArrayOfGeneralAgent:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Agents", propOrder = {
    "generalAgent"
})
public class ArrayOfGeneralAgent {

@XmlElement(name = "GeneralAgent", nillable = true)
        protected List<GeneralAgent> generalAgent;

...
}
```

From Above code expecting below xml:

```
<Agents>
  <GeneralAgent>
    <ComPerc>1.5</ComPerc>
    <CustID>abc</CustID>
    <SharePerc>123</SharePerc>
  </GeneralAgent>
</Agents>
```

But getting XML like this:

```
<ArrayOfGeneralAgent>
  <GeneralAgent>
    <ComPerc>1.5</ComPerc>
    <CustID>abc</CustID>
    <SharePerc>123</SharePerc>
  </GeneralAgent>
</ArrayOfGeneralAgent>
```

Instead of "Agents" getting "ArrayOfGeneralAgent".

I tried to many things but nothing found.

Comment: Did you try to add @XmlRootElement(name = "Agents") as an annotation above public class ArrayOfGeneralAgent

Comment: Yes, I added @XmlRootElement(name = "Agents") annotation above public class ArrayOfGeneralAgent. But getting same output.

Comment: Try removing name attribute from @XmlElementRef(name... and add @XmlRootElement(name = "Agents") to ArrayOfGeneralAgent. Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `@XmlElementRef.name` does not work for `@XmlRootElement`, read about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html).

What you have to do is to remove the attribute *name* from `XmlElementRef` on your xml element.

```
@XmlElementRef(type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfGeneralAgent> agents;
```

and add `@XmlRootElement` to your class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Agents")
public class ArrayOfGeneralAgent{...}
```